# How to pass a variable in Rails find_by_sql and group_by

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 tables. due_loans and payments. Payments table has due_loan_id. Now I want to find all payments belonging to a due loan and perform the calculations in a below SQL.
This sql query is working perfectly in MySQL workbench. However, I am unable to make work in Rails. I don't know how to pass variables and group in find_by_sql.

```
select d.id dueid, d.issue_loan_id, d.duedate,d.dueamount, sum(ifnull(amount, 0))paid, dueamount - sum(ifnull(amount, 0))balance from due_loans d
left join payments p
on d.id = p.due_loan_id
where d.issue_loan_id = 15
group by dueid
```

If there is no payment for a corresponding due loan then I am assigning a 0 for calculations. Among other solutions, this is what I tried.

```
  def get_due_loans_results
   @dueloans = DueLoan.find_by_sql(["select d.id dueid, d.issue_loan_id, d.duedate, d.dueamount, sum(ifnull(amount, 0))paid, dueamount - sum(ifnull(amount, 0))balance from due_loans d
                                left join payments p
                                on d.id = p.due_loan_id
                                where d.issue_loan_id =?", params[:issue_loan_id]].group_by => 'dueid')
   respond_to do |format|
   format.json  {render json: @dueloans}
  end
end
```

[image: MySQL screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like:

```
DueLoan.find_by_sql(["select d.id dueid, d.issue_loan_id, d.duedate, d.dueamount, sum(ifnull(amount, 0))paid, dueamount - sum(ifnull(amount, 0))balance from due_loans d
                                left join payments p
                                on d.id = p.due_loan_id
                                where d.issue_loan_id = ? group by dueid", params[:issue_loan_id]])
```

Comment: Now I have and it works. I thought group is always a last argument. Thanks a lot.